# How To Use Mapstate to map this data

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I can take data from `this.$store.state.workermanage.staff.staff`

but how can I exchange this code by using ...mapstate, thanks

`persons: this.$store.state.workermanage.staff.staff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({ persons: state => state.workermanage.staff.staff })
}
```

And use like:

```html
{{ persons }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) for the nested `staff` object in store.js

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    workmanage: {
        staff: {
            staff: {

            } 
        }
    }
  },
  getters: {
    nestedStaff: state => {
      return state.workamage.staff.staff
    }
  }
})
```

Use the getter in your component:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'nestedStaff'
    ])
  }
}
```

After that, you can use `nestedStaff` as it was a simple computed property.